# Get-Member for System.NullableType<T>

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

How do I get the members of an open type such as, say, `System.Nullable<T>`?

I tried:

```
> [System.Nullable[T]] | Get-Member
```

But that results in the following error:

```
Unable to find type [T].
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.Nullable[T]] | Get-Member
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (T:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

If I try to get it for the closed type `Nullable<int>`, for example, I do not see any of the methods of the type. Instead, it shows me the members of `TypeName: System.RuntimeType`.

```
> [System.Nullable[int]] | Get-Member
```

The same happens if I try for `System.DateTime`. Or for a reference type such as `System.String`.

I am assuming it is because `Get-Member` expects an *object* as its input rather than a type name. And so it considers the type name I specify as an object of `System.RuntimeType`.

1 . How do I see the members of a type?

2. Also, I'd like to see the static members included in there as well. So, when I do call `Get-Member` on an object instance like so:

   4 | Get-Member

I'd like the static members also to show up.

Comment: `[System.Nullable] | Get-Member -Force; [System.Nullable] | Get-Member -Static`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks. That `-Static` switch gives me the static members. Is it possible to enlist the members of a type just given the type name and not given an object of the type?

Answer (score 1):

First, to resolve a generic type without the type parameters you need to use this syntax:

```
[Nullable`1]
```

The second issue is getting members from types is a little obtuse without community modules.  You can do this

```
[Nullable`1].DeclaredMembers | Format-Table Name, MemberType
```

You'll want to adjust the properties in `Format-Table` to what you want to see.

You may want to check out either the [Reflection](https://github.com/Jaykul/Reflection) or [Poke](https://github.com/oising/poke) community modules to make it a little easier as well.